# Assembly x86 error with SHL eax, ecx

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers, instruction-set, operands

Im having trouble with this compile error in my code for an Assembly x86 class,

> A2070: invalid instruction operands

the line is

```
shl eax, ecx
```

`ecx` should be looping (decreasing by 1) and never be greater than 5 at this moment, so why can't I shift the value? I need to multiply the value in `eax` by 2^n, n being the value in `ecx`, with shift left.

```
createArray PROC   
;saving 5 multiples of the value currently in eax into an array addres that 
is ;on the stack
    push ecx       
    push eax
    push esi
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov ecx, 5
    mov esi, [ebp+24] ;address of array
    L1:
        call multiply   ;call multiply with two numbers eax, ecx
        pop eax
        mov [esi],eax
        add esi, 4

    Loop L1
....cont
createArray endp

multiply PROC
    shl eax, ecx ; this line right here
    push eax
multiply endp
```

if I substitute

```
shl eax, 5
```

then it works I just don't know why ecx doesn't work.

Comment: It's not clear why you push/pop eax (and omit the ret?).  Is this because you have omitted code for simplicity?  And if you remove the push/pop/ret, there isn't much reason to do a call.  Just put the shl into the loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shift instructions [don't accept a 32-bit register as their count operand](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_285.html).

You'll want to use the lower bits in `cl`:

```
shl eax, cl
```